# group homomorphisms from the real line to infinite torsion abelian groups

Tags: group-theory

Hello I have question in group theory that actually originated from a question in dynamical systems.

Let G be the abelian group given by the real line with addition. Let H be an infinite torsion abelian group (i.e. all its elements are torsion). 
Now if the order of the elements of H is uniformly bounded by a constant, then it is elementary to see that there is only the trivial group homomorphism from G to H, namely the one that send G to the identity of H.

I am wondering if the same is true if one skips the requirement about the uniform bound for the order of the elements of $H$. Namely is it true that in any case there can only be the trivial homomorphism sending G to the identity of H? (notice, I do not put any topology on H, this is just a group homomorphism).

thank you.

Comment: Unless you are interested in the dependence of this on the axiom of choice, this isn't really research-level.  Consider the group $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Off-topic: why is there exactly one mathematical symbol in your question that deserves MathJaXification, while all the others have to be satisfied with plain cold sans-serif typesetting?

Comment: @user66257 — The group $\mathbb{R}$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. (Maybe this helps to see why Eric Wofsey's comment is relevant.)

Answer (score 2):

As a complement to the excellent answer by Simone, here's some more about abelian groups.

In what follows, *group* will mean *abelian group* (written additively).

A group $G$ is *divisible* if, for all $x\in G$ and all integers $n>0$, there is $y\in G$ so that $x=ny$. It is not hard to show that

- every divisible subgroup of a group is a direct summand;
- the sum of all divisible subgroups of a group is a divisible subgroup;
- if $f\colon G\to G'$ is a group homomorphism and $G$ is divisible, then $f(G)$ is a divisible subgroup of $G'$.

In particular every group $G$ can be written as $G=D\oplus R$, where $D$ is the maximum divisible subgroup and $R$ (not uniquely determined) is a *reduced* group, that is, its only divisible subgroup is $\{0\}$.

The group of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ is obviously divisible, so there's only the trivial homomorphism $\mathbb{R}\to G$, when $G$ is a reduced group.

If $G$ is a torsion group with finite exponent (there is $n>0$ so that $nG=\{0\}$)  is obviously reduced. In your terminology it is the same as *bounded*.

Conversely, it can be proved that if $G$ is divisible, then it is possible to find cardinal numbers $\alpha_0$ and $\alpha_p$ (for each prime $p$) so that
$$
G=\mathbb{Q}^{(\alpha_0)}\oplus\bigoplus_p \mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)^{(\alpha_p)}
$$
where $X^{(\alpha)}$ means a direct sum of $\alpha$ copies of $X$ and, for each prime $p$, $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ is the Prüfer $p$-group. Those cardinal numbers are a complete set of invariants for $G$.

In particular, if $\alpha_\infty$ is the supremum of the cardinal numbers $\alpha_p$ ($p$ a prime) in the decomposition above, there is a surjective group homomorphism $\mathbb{Q}^{(\alpha_0)}\oplus\mathbb{Q}^{(\alpha_\infty)}\to G$, because
$$
\bigoplus_p \mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)\cong \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}.
$$

Since $\mathbb{R}$ has $0$-invariant $2^{\aleph_0}$, we can see that there is a surjective group homomorphism $\mathbb{R}\to G$, where $G$ is a divisible group, if and only if all the invariants of $G$ are less than or equal to $2^{\aleph_0}$.

In any case, for every non reduced group $G$, there is a non trivial group homomorphism $\mathbb{R}\to G$, just because there is a non trivial homomorphism $\mathbb{Q}\to G$.

Answer (score 1):

As an Abelian group, $\mathbb R$ is just a direct sum of $|\mathbb R|$-many copies of $\mathbb Q$. Since $\mathbb Z$ is a hereditary Noetherian ring, and $\mathbb Q$ is injective, also $\mathbb R$ is injective as a $\mathbb Z$-module and all of its quotients are injective. Since no injective Abelian group is bounded, this explains your first claim. 
On the other hand, $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ is an injective cogenerator of $\mathrm {Mod-}\mathbb Z$, and it is torsion (it is the direct sum of the Prüfer groups, one copy for each prime). Thus, not only $\mathbb R$, but any non-trivial Abelian group, admits a non-trivial homomorphism to $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$.

In particular you can find a surjective homomorphism $\mathbb R\to \mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$.

If you want something more, in Theorem 3.5 of [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235779890_Fully_inert_subgroups_of_divisible_Abelian_groups) you can find a characterization of the Abelian groups that admit a surjective homomorphism onto some Prüfer group (of course, this is classical, we just gave a complete proof as we could not find an easily accessible reference).

Answer (score 0):

Since $\mathbb{R}$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, pick a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis and choose one basis vector (axiom of choice), and this gives you a projection $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Q}$.

Compose this with the quotient map $\mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ to obtain a non-trivial homomorphism $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.